# Submitting screenshots in the app store for an AR app

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, appstore-approval

I'm about to submit my AR app to the app store. How do I generate screenshots for different devices? Opening the app in the Xcode simulator and making a screenshot doesn't work since the app needs camera access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a screenshot in running AR app on iPhone X and later press:

<kbd>Side Power</kbd> button + <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> button simultaneously.

[image]

To generate a screenshot in running AR app on iPhone 8 and earlier press:

<kbd>Side Power</kbd> button + <kbd>Home</kbd> button simultaneously.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solution requires that you have all physical the required iPhone and iPads for generating various screenshots in order to submit an app in the app store. Is there a way to generate these screenshots without having to buy all those devices?

Comment: AR app must be running on a real device only, so there's no any other way.